# GROUP BY SUM ON pandas data frame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

df:

```
a b class
0 0  +
0 1  +
1 0  -
```

expected output:

```
group each column based on class value and find the count, 
as in taking column 'a' as example the count should be 2 
for class '+' and 1 for class '-'
```

Code:

```
grp = df.groupby(df.class, axis=1).sum()
```

getting errors which I dont even understand. new to pandas, any suggestions would be great.

Comment: you don't need to specify the axis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

`print(sample.groupby('class').count())`